# How to produce an effect when a checkbox button is checked while using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying jQuery from scratch & I want to produce an effect when a checkbox button was checked, with jQuery. But I'm not having the effect I want.

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb">
    <label for="cb">Show Button</label>
</div>
<button id="but">
    Button
</button>
```

```
$(() => {
    $("#but").hide();
    $("#cb").on("change", () => {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#but").show();
        }
    });
});
```

I realized it is not entering to the if block. I guess `checked` prop should be called on a different way?  How can I make this work?

Comment: Your event `change` is fine, it's just that `()=>` does not set `this` to the element.  Use `$("#cb").on("change", function() {` if you want to use `this`  https://jsfiddle.net/jo38uynh/

Comment: @freedomn-m, is there a way to do it with arrow functions?

Comment: As noted on the link, change `$(this)` to `$(event.currentTarget)` if you're using `() =>`

Comment: @freedomn-m, yes but I forgot to pass `(event) =>{}`, thanks!